# XMLHttpRequestObject.status return 0, however I can see in fiddler that the response is fully received

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I use an XMLHttpRequestOject to get content from a third party site. When executing my script, I have [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) running and I can see that the response is fully received (200 ok). However the XMLHttpRequestObject.status is always 0 (I don't get the 200) while the XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState is 4. I'm assuming that the browser is actually blocking the response then (and not the server getting the request).

Is there any workaround, from the client side to enable the browser to display the received response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the browser is blocking this as [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Two ways around this are [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) and [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).